# input html com gin o golang

Tags: html, postgresql, go

I made a simple crud, using golang, gin, gorm and postgres.
i want to integrate to frontend using html.
I managed to list my insert operations using html, now I want to do the user creation part. what i want is:
put employee information in an html input, click on a Submit button and this information is added to my database.

I didn't complete any attempts, as I'm a complete beginner. I want some solution to be able to study and be able to do

I have this struct:

`

```
type Funcionarios struct {
    IDFuncionario       int    `json:"id_funcionario" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    NomeFuncionario     string `json:"nome_funcionario"`
    IdadeFuncionario    int    `json:"idade_funcionario"`
    EnderecoFuncionario string `json:"endereco_funcionario"`
    FuncaoFuncionario   string `json:"funcao_funcionario"`
    SalarioFuncionario  int    `json:"salario_funcionario"`
    DataContratacao     string `json:"data_contratacao_funcionario"`
}
```

`

and I have these lines of code:

`

```
func (h handler) createFuncionario(c *gin.Context) {

    var addFunc Funcionarios
    c.ShouldBindJSON(&addFunc)

    h.db.Create(&addFunc)
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "Criado": addFunc,
    })
}
func (h handler) listFuncionarioHTML(c *gin.Context) {

    var listFuncHTML []Funcionarios
    h.db.Find(&listFuncHTML)

    listFuncHTML = append(listFuncHTML, Funcionarios{})
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", gin.H{
        "listFunc": listFuncHTML,
    })
    //c.JSON(200, listFunc)
func main() {
    dbload := Init()
    h := OpenDB(dbload)
    router := gin.Default()
    users := router.Group("users")
    router.LoadHTMLFiles("templates/index.html")

    {

        users.POST("/create", h.createFuncionario)

        users.GET("/listAlter", h.listFuncionarioAlter)
        users.PUT("/update/:id_funcionario", h.updateFuncionario)
        users.GET("/listHTML", h.listFuncionarioHTML)
        users.GET("/list", h.listFuncionario)

    }
    router.Run(":8086")
}
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it with another simple example, but it works too.

CODE GO:

```html
func (h handler) postform(c *gin.Context) {
    var users = []Users{{Nome: c.Request.PostFormValue("nome"), Email: c.Request.PostFormValue("email")}, {}}

    h.DB.Create(&users)
}
```

CODE HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Upe seu usuario</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Upe seu usuario</h1>

<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input placeholder="Nome" type="text" name="nome"><br><br>
     <input placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside the root project I have the folders: public/index.html

CODE MAIN.GO:

```
func main() {
db := Init()
h := openDB(db)
r := gin.Default()

r.Static("/", "./public")
//r.GET("/listarUsuario", h.listUser)
r.POST("/upload", h.postform)
r.POST("/criarUsuario", h.criarUser)

r.Run(":7878")
```

}